# Is everything in organic chemistry arbitrary?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I am a student who is trying to study organic chemistry. I'm using McMurry's book for it. As a beginner in chemistry, I have a fundamental question about chemistry itself. Are most of the chemistry's reaction rules, proved in a way of experiment and probability? Especially for organic chemistry. I really can't get why the reactions occur and there seem to be too many exceptions. When I ask teachers, they say it is because they just found them by experiment. But it seems to be too much for to just say that all the knowledge is just from experiences. There must be some fundamental rules.

So my question is

- How do we find organic chemistry reactions?
- Where do we use the reactions that we find in books?
- Are there other important rules in a molecule or the electrons that are in the molecule besides the induction and resonance effect?
- Can't organic chemistry be more rigid (I can't find a good word for this)? Studying McMurry's book, the products of the reactions seems to be determined arbitrarily.

Comment: Read Clayden and throw McMurry away...

Comment: I might not go as far as @orthocresol suggests, but you're asking good questions and I think going beyond McMurry might be a good idea.

Comment: :D I cannot conscientiously recommend that anyone use McMurry though. The book is organised by functional group (a very poor organisation imo) and reads much more like a *list* of reactions. There's far too little conceptual reinforcement. Lots of useless figures (in particular, the repetitive electron density plots irritated me). Trust me - many people I know picked up Clayden and never looked back. I can't say it has all your answers but it is a huge improvement.

Comment: However, Anslyn and Dougherty is great way to understand just how arbitrary organic chemistry **isn't**, when you want to make the jump into hardcore physical organic chemistry.

Comment: BTW, I am going to VTC as too broad. If you split them up into multiple questions, I would love to write some answers. But as it stands, each bullet point warrants an entire essay.

Comment: Functional group makes little sense, but that's how the old school guys do it.

Comment: I throw in a bit here. First organic chemistry is really about trying to make some particular compound. What do you have to start from and what reactions to get there... // Studying in a book is good, but a lab to go with the book learning is really helpful. Products are rarely 100% yield. Incomplete reactions, and side reactions are the norm. Purifying a compound made is also sometimes quite a challenge. The hands-on effort is really helpful.

Comment: @MaxW, as an organic chemist "raised" as a physical organic chemist now working in a natural product synthesis lab, I don't know whether to begrudgingly agree or to argue vehemently. There's two sides to that coin. This isn't wrong, but I also think it's incomplete.

Comment: @DGS - I agree that the answer is dumb downed. The point that I was trying to make is that in general you don't want just to make "some" product. The art in organic chemistry is getting a good yield of a high purity product. Thus some "textbook reactions" wouldn't really work in an industrial plant.